# Keyboard shortcut for renaming a Jupyter lab notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I wonder if there is a **keyboard shortcut** for quickly renaming a **Jupyter Lab** notebook. (<kbd>F2</kbd> would be great, but it does not work).

I know how to rename by right-clicking the file name from the 'Files' section, or right-clicking the notebook tab name which is explained [here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/notebook.html). But none of these are convenient for me, simply I don't want to move my hand to mouse for renaming, I want to use a keyboard shortcut for this task.

Did anyone figure out how to do this?

Comment: In JupyterLab 3.4.3 / Chrome 102 / Windows 10 **`F2`** works but very unreliably: Sometimes I have to press **`F2`** twice, sometimes I have to move the file selection up/down before **`F2`** works. --- Originally I thought it does not work at all. --- The shortcut is there since JupyterLab 3.1: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/2814

Answer (score 2):

In the settings editor, you can map this to e.g. Accel (Mac "command") + R by adding the following to list of "shortcuts" in User Preferences :

```
{
    "shortcuts": [
        {"command": "filebrowser:rename",
         "keys": ["Accel R"],
         "selector": "body"
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes this works well. But If anyone prefers to use "F2" then only needs to change  this line "keys": ["F2"],